# header location not working but stuck in page

Tags: php, header, location

so I have a button

```
<input type="button" value="add" onclick="document.location.href='add.php?myUcode=<?=$row['ucode'];?>'" />
```

to another page (let's call it Page1). in Page1, I want to add a value to $_SESSION['employees'] and then redirect it back to home.php. but when I click the button, it gets stuck in add.php. there is no echo or whitespace before I call the Header method. now I have no idea what is wrong with my code :

```
<?php
session_start();
if ($_POST['tambah_ucode']) {
if (isset($_SESSION['jum_petugas'])) {
    $_SESSION['jum_petugas'] = 1;
    $ctr = $_SESSION['jum_petugas'];
} else {
    $ctr = $_SESSION['jum_petugas'];
    $ctr++;
    $_SESSION['jum_petugas'] = $ctr;
}
$_SESSION['ucode_petugas'][$ctr] = $_POST['tambah_ucode'];
header('Location: localhost/hrm2.1/lembur_add.php');
}
?>
```

Comment: try something like this: header('Location: lembur_add.php');

Comment: @SureshKamrushi still doesn't work...

Comment: I re-read my previous pages and found out that I realized that the variable 'tambah_ucode' was passed in the URL so I should've used $_GET instead of $_POST.. it works now. thanks guys.

how do I set this question as "answered" or something?

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
header('Location: lembur_add.php');
exit;
```

**OR**

```
header('Location: http://localhost/hrm2.1/lembur_add.php');
exit;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
header('location:localhost/hrm2.1/lembur_add.php')
```

without space

Comment: This will make no sense.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following

`header('Location:http://localhost/hrm2.1/lembur_add.php');`

Answer (score 0):

Instead of header(...), try

```
echo "<script type='text/javascript'> document.location = 'yourLocation'; </script>";
```